# how to fix error message e:/unable to mount usbstorage on Samsung Note 3 - Sprint Variant

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3, twrp, cyanogenmod

I have the above device rooted and installed custom recover twrp 2.6.x.x. I keep seeing the message: unable to moutn e:/usbstorage. And I think this is messing with my attempt to install Cyanogenmod 11. I checked the MD5 hash of Cyanogenmod and it is good. I have also tried older versions from the same nightly page. I just get this one error. When I flash the phone, if I ask twrp to check the MD5, it fails. If don't ask for it, it says that there is no hash file and reports that install was a success. But instead the phone goes into a boot loop. I saw this link about the same issue on a different phone. Here is the link [Script / Fix Soft Brick Loop_ EFS partition_01.11.13](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2507403&highlight=note) Some of the people on the site say that the script worked for their Note 3. Others say that the script is not for Note 3. Also the download site seems to be malicious ( according to my malware software; so I can not download it ). I need help to fix this issue. I do have a stock image to flash my phone if anything breaks. I also have the rooting and twrp flashing tools and procedures. I do it in my sleep now. I do not know if I should start messing with PIT files.

Comment: Where do you keep seeing that message? At what stage of the process?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out the issue was with the image I was using. My experience was that all of the CyanogenMod 11 nightlies created the loop, and the only version that worked for me was the "snapshot" build.

Comment: You should elaborate as then your answer will be more useful to others that might have this issue in the future.

Comment: Oh sure. I'll be glad to. There is a comment about boot loop associated with Cyanogenmod 11, but there are no details. My experience was that all of the Cyanogenmod 11 nightlys created the loop, and the only version that worked for me was the snapshot. There are various levels of maturity for the code, which are as follows: stable, release candidate, snapshot, milestone, nightly, and experiments.Btw, I don't know the difference between each of these categories. Currently Note 3 just has the nightly and the snapshot.